# removing <p> tags around img, iframes and also scripts

Tags: the-content, embed

I've been working with embeded content and as many already know, wordpress wraps the_content() lines in p tags.

So, found this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
```

When I change "iframe" by "script" it works, but then only for one of them, I need both beacuse the twitter embbeds create a hidden script element wich in turn creates a ghost paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it and also remove `<p>` tags from images that are linked.

Why it removes it from only one `<script>` instance is hard to tell. Would have to see your website code to investigate further.

```
// Remove p tags from images, scripts, and iframes.
function remove_some_ptags( $content ) {
  $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
  $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<script.*>*.<\/script>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
  $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe.*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_some_ptags' );
```

Comment: That workes well for "scripts" yet, "iframes" went back to being wrapped around -p- tags, still wondering how to get it right. Thanks

Comment: @FernandoYP - okay, didn't realize you wanted to also exclude iframe tags. I've revised the code so try it again.

Comment: That worked just fine @chicoman98. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript function that does it:

```
moveIframesOutOfPtags() {
  let iframes = document.querySelectorAll( 'iframe' );

  let before = "<div class="iframe-container">";
  let after = "</div>";

  Object.entries( iframes ).forEach( entry => {
    let value = entry[1];

    if( value.parentNode.nodeName === 'P' || value.parentNode.nodeName === 'p' ){
      value.parentNode.outerHTML = before + value.parentNode.innerHTML + after;
    }
  });
}
```

I've written a few more details [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989733/strip-automatic-p-tags-around-images-videos-iframes-in-wordpress-4-9/59946156#59946156).